# How to find average score in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "id": "onslaught", 
  "name":"abc",
  "type": "bread",
  "powers": [
       {"grade": "A", "Rating": 3}, 
       {"grade": "B", "Rating": 5}, 
       {"grade": "A", "Rating": 2},
       {"grade": "B", "Rating": 5}, 
       {"grade": "A", "Rating": 7}, 
       {"grade": "A", "Rating": 7}
    ]
}
```

Need to find out the  average score of each restaurant in the  type =bread.

Comment: You have to use an aggregation query with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#calculate-count-sum-and-average) pipeline stage. The provided link has some examples, similar to what you are trying to do; please try that.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer if you need [`unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) [`group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  [`avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

```
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$powers",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        average: {
            "$avg": "$powers.Rating"
        }
    }
}
```